# Find prime ideals of Quotient Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $R$ be the ring $\Bbb C[x]/(x^2+1)$. Pick the correct statements from below:
>
> 1. $\dim_\Bbb C R=3$.
> 2. $R$ has exactly two prime ideals.
> 3. $R$ is a UFD.
> 4. $(x)$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

First option is wrong as the dimension of $R$ over $\Bbb C$ is $2$. For $3$rd option, $\Bbb C[x]/(x^2+1)$ is isomorphic to  $\Bbb C×\Bbb C$. But  $\Bbb C× \Bbb C$ is not a UFD. Hence 3 is wrong. Is my justification for $3$rd option right? I don't know how to find the ideals of quotient ring. Please help me in understanding second and fourth option.

Comment: 4. $x^2+1=0$ in $R$, so $x$ is invertible and hence $(x)=R$.

Answer (score 1):

As you said $$R=\mathbb C[x]/(x^2+1)\cong\mathbb C[x]/(x-i)\times\mathbb C[x]/(x+i)\cong \mathbb C\times\mathbb C$$

Now,

1. $R/P$ is an integral domain $\iff P$ is a prime ideal
2. $R/P$ is a field $\iff P$ is a maximal ideal

For $R$ to be field or integral domain you need to define a map $$R/P\rightarrow \mathbb C$$ This is accomplished by either one of the projections:

1. $(z,w)\mapsto z$
2. $(z,w)\mapsto w$

Which corresponds to the prime (and maximal) ideals $(x+i), (x-i)$.